# combobox to update adjacent cell in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview with a combobox that looks up at a different table called products and enables me to select a product. I also set the datagridview tag to lookup to the same table "products" at the price column. I want to be able to auto-populate the price cell by selecting a product off the combobox. The problem is that the code below changes the entire column to the same price. I only want that particular row to change.

I have the following code on the datagridview.cellvaluechanged event. By the way... I use VB.net. Please, no C# answers.

```
    Dim price As Double = 0


    price = Recipe_DetailsDataGridView.Tag
    For Each column As DataRowView In Me.Recipe_DetailsBindingSource.List
        column!price = price

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are looping through all the rows, why are you surprised that all the rows change?  If you only want to change one row then just change one row, which does not involve a loop.  The event you are using should give you the row index, so you can get the cell from the appropriate column in the same row or you can get the bound item and set the appropriate field.

By the way, does it really make sense to name that loop control variable 'column' when it represents a row?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm asking the experts. I saw this code somewhere else. I did try using just a method but didn't work. I am very new to this. started writing code about a month ago. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, the event you are using provides the row index.  The first thing to do is to read about the event then.  Once you have the row index you can get the row.  Once you have the row you either get the cell in the desired column and set its Value or get the DataBoundItem and modify it directly.

Comment: no success. spent hours trying to figure out how to do that. I guess I gotta have to read more books. An example would have been helpful though.

Comment: How about you show us what you think it should be and then we'll help you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I have. I had a vague idea and was able to accomplish a message box to display the row index.

Dim index As Integer

```
    For i = 0 To Recipe_DetailsDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count - 1

        index = Recipe_DetailsDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex
        MsgBox(index, , )
```

Answer (score 0):

did it! The first lines I kind of got them from an old VBA project and simply implemented it according to .net
The last line just snap out of my head right now.

Dim index As Integer

```
    For i = 0 To Recipe_DetailsDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count - 1

        index = Recipe_DetailsDataGridView.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex
        Recipe_DetailsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = Recipe_DetailsDataGridView.Tag
```